# Can I enter Canada with previous entry denial into another country?

Tags: canada, international-travel, visa-refusals, study, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry into Thailand on two consecutive attempts in 2014. I recently got admission into a college in Canada and I am applying for a study permit. Does my previous travel history affect my application and/or entry into Canada? I am from Cameroon.

Comment: By "admission into Canada" do you mean you got accepted by a University as a student in Canada and are applying for a student visa?

Answer (score 2):

It might, it might not. It depends on the reason for the denial.

All you can do is be honest. If at any point you are asked whether you've previously been denied entry, you need to tell the truth.  If it's in paperwork, attach a letter explaining clearly the reasons for the denial.  Don't blame the system or the government or whatever, just state the facts of the events and the reasons given by Thailand.

If it's something that Canada decides doesn't affect them, or wasn't too 'bad', they may choose to ignore it.

It's also possible Canada only asks whether you've been previously denied entry into Canada.  In this case, you'll happily be able to answer 'no'.

Whatever happens, be honest. If you try to cover it up and they have some data sharing with Thailand or somehow find out from another source that you've lied to them, it's a massive blow to your chances of getting a visa. So be open and honest, and let us know how it goes!

Comment: Actually, I do not know the reason(s) for denial, so I do not know what exactly to include in my explanation. The writings in my passport are very small and in Thai language.
However, On the first attempt, I a friend translated the writing on my passport to mean "insufficient funds". I have no idea what the second refusal could be as I have not been able to find someone to help me translate.

I was on a tourist visa.

Comment: In that case, say that, and if possible, just include copies of the denial (if they ask about non-Canadian denials). If they really want, they'll translate them themselves, and your openness will look good, hopefully.

Comment: I am also worried about the time period from my last entry denial in Thailand, to my present application for a TRV to Canada.

Could such reasons for denial cause a visa or TRV refusal?

Comment: @Dorian same applies.  Be open and honest about your reasons, explain everything clearly in a letter if possible.  Unanswered questions or unexplained stuff raises more concerns than something you can explain.

Comment: Denied Entries noted in your passport will be seen by the consular official reviewing your visa application.  And they will look into what they were for, don't assume they won't bother translating Thai.  As your first denial was for "insufficient funds", I would make sure you can present solid proof of your financial ability to live & study in Canada.  I would also try and find out what the 2nd denial was for so as to be prepared for any questions or additional documentation that might cause.

Comment: @Dorian - suggestion, Google Translate in your phone (if you don't have it, find someone who does) now handles on-the-fly translation of Thai writing.  So that may well help give you a rough translation and perhaps the reason for denial.